# How to save VS Code state

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to develop my solution in two different computer (one in office and one in home), and want to save VS Code working state (eg. which file is last edited) to some file so that I can save it to git.

Comment: Unfortunately VS Code doesn't support this at this stage. What you're after is for VS Code to keep track of the files you edited along with the changes you made in the cloud. This is what a git and other version control systems do well. So, you might want to consider making your changes in a separate branch and committing your changes regularly. This way your changes are always accessible.

Comment: @Don Thanks, I already used git to store changes. I just want to restore VS Code working status, the layout and the files currently editing. seems no solutions now.